# xml file issue while importing my source code into My Eclipse Blue 2014

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad, ibm-was

I was using RAD and WAS to run my ear application. Now I am migrating RAD to Eclipse Blue and facing a compilation error as:

```
    Referenced file contains errors (file:/C:/DEVTOOLS/MyEclipseBlue2014/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1128/1/.cp/dtds/loose.dtd). 
 For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."
```

My XML file is as :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <security-role name="ValidUser">
    <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS"/>

  </security-role>
```

Could any one of you help me to figure the cause for this error and how can I resolve it?